# how can I find out during a touch and moving a finger, user touched a specific view in react native?

Tags: react-native

In React Native, I have several boxes(Views) in my screen. I want to know if user cross one of the boxes or not during his/her touch event.
for instance if user touched box1 I want to alert him 'you move from box 1' and so on...

I couldn't find any solution for that. please help me with some advices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [PanResponder's documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder), you can use the X and Y position returned from the touch event to determine on which view his finger is.

You can also use the [gesture responder system](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system). this is mentioned in the docs:

> View.props.onResponderTerminationRequest: (evt) => true - Something
> else wants to become responder. Should this view release the
> responder? Returning true allows release
>
> View.props.onResponderTerminate: (evt) => {} - The responder has been
> taken from the View. Might be taken by other views after a call to
> onResponderTerminationRequest, or might be taken by the OS without
> asking (happens with control center/ notification center on iOS)

Comment: in this solution I need to get each view's X-start, X-end, Y-start, Y-end position. and after that always check user's finger x,y to see if it's in that area or not.
But it's not accurate.
Is there any other way, which each views listen for touch event and if it happens they trigger a function?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample for your second solution?
I think all these methods works for a box if touch event start on that box.
I mean other boxes wont listen anymore.
if user continue his finger on screen to other box, that box wont do anything.
is that correct?